# How to add bootstrap datetimepicker in Symfony form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, datepicker

I'm trying to use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ in my Symfony form.

I added:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css') }}">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset('assets/js/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
```

But now I'm not sure how do I change my form type to use datepicker

I tried something like this and it's not working

```
->add('date', DateTimeType::class, array(
'required' => true,
'widget' => 'single_text',
'attr' => [
    'class' => 'form-control input-inline datetimepicker',
    'data-provide' => 'datetimepicker',
    'html5' => false,
],
))
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given approach? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385390

Answer (score 0):

You should move the html5 key/value from attr to options :

```
->add('date', DateTimeType::class, array(
'required' => true,
'widget' => 'single_text',
'html5' => false,
'attr' => [
    'class' => 'form-control input-inline datetimepicker',
    'data-provide' => 'datetimepicker',
],
))
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem. The default Form-Component from Symfony for Datetime type render an other set of input fields.

The bootstrap approach expect a "normal" input field with a DateTime rendered as a string. So you have to use **TextType::class**
To work with a DateTime in the Entity i've added an EntityTransformer to handle the conversion between sting and DateTime for read and write operations.

you can do it like this:

```
$builder->get( 'from' )->addModelTransformer( new CallbackTransformer(
    function ( $date ) {
        return $date->format( 'd.m.Y H:i' );
    },
    function ( $date ) {
        return new \DateTime( $date );
    }
) );
```

Comment: No, that's not needed - that's what the `single_text` option is set for

Comment: You have to use a TextType:::class to get the frontend part working with the bootstrap js, as the topic is called. When you want to store the value in DateTime-Type in the DB you have to transform the values. I can't see the point where this is not needed

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure it is the unique issue, but you might need to change DateTimeType::class to texttype::class.

I hope this can help! 
good luck

Comment: No, that's not needed - that's what the `single_text` option is set for