# How to "install" Bootstrap Datetimepicker on Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, yarnpkg, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have files like `assets/css/bootstrap-4.3.1.css` and `assets/js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js` and in `webpack.config` I have

```
.addEntry('js/bootstrap','./assets/js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js')
```

and

```
.addStyleEntry('css/bootstrap', './assets/css/bootstrap-4.3.1.css')
```

I need `bootstrap-3.3.1.js` and `bootstrap-3.3.1.css`, respectively.

I need to install these in yarn in order to ensure that I have my perequisites for Bootstrap datetimepicker. Tried with

```
yarn add bootstrap@3.3.1
```

without any luck. Then I tried to download the files manually into assets/css and assets/js, respectively and ran the command above again, without any luck. So, I need to use yarn to change the version of Bootstrap. Then, I will need to use Bootstrap datetimepicker as well. How can I achieve my goal? Linking the css and js files manually at this point seems to be extremely for me in comparison to using yarn, but it is highly probable that the cause is just my lack of knowledge about yarn.

EDIT

At this point I have

**package.json**

```
//...
"depencencies": {
    //...
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
    //...
}
//...
```

**app.js**

```
//...
require("bootstrap");
//...
```

Error message when running `yarn install`:

This dependency was not found:

> - bootstrap in ./assets/js/app.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save bootstrap

Comment: @msg what would the effect be in that case? I suppose your suggestion is to add this line and then run yarn install. Is that correct?

Comment: @msg thanks for your comments so far, however, not knowing much of these things, they are still unclear for me. I would like to have bootstrap-3.3.1. By creating a line saying require('bootstrap') how will it know the version of my preference? app.js already has a line, saying import "bootstrap";. Knowing these where should I put require('bootstrap') inside the file? Is it indifferent?

Comment: @msg I cannot make it work, obviously, I do not know how yarn works and didn't find sources which explain in an easy manner how it should be used. I guess I will just link css and js manually, it's more effective as far as I know than yarn.

Comment: @msg Symfony docs gives me no clue about versions here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html

Comment: @msg I have edited my question. I have done yarn add bootstrap@3.3.1, I have added require('bootstrap'), yet it cannot find it. I have even downloaded bootstrap 3.3.1.zip and attempted to yarn add it, but was not successful in doing it, even after converting to tar.gz, due to a yarn bug. It has a solution (https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/509/files) but do we really need to start developing yarn in order to install Bootstrap datetimepicker via yarn?

Comment: @msg Attempted with require("bootstrap@3.3.1"); without any success.

Comment: `yarn install` shouldn't look into app.js when installing packages, just package.json and yarn.lock. app.js is only relevant when running webpack So I have no idea as to what could be happening. The only thing I can think of is to delete `node_modules` or run `yarn install --force`.

Comment: @msg I need to run yarn run encore dev. The error happens then. However, it's very simple to see that nothing works if I try to find bootstrap 3.3.1 in the assets folder.

Comment: You run `yarn run dev` *after* `yarn add bootstrap@3.3.1 && yarn install`. The installation does not copy bootstrap into the assets/ folder, but into node_modules/. Does that folder exist and is bootstrap in there?

Comment: @msg yes, node_modules folder exists, I can find a bootstrap folder inside it and both bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js have a version of 3.4.1 (pretty close, but not exact match to the version I specified).

Comment: @msg however, yarn install runs successfully, but yarn run encore dev errors out due to require('bootstrap'); because it doesn't find bootstrap files in the assets folder of the project.

Comment: This dependency was not found:

* bootstrap in ./assets/js/app.js

Comment: .addEntry('bootstrap', './assets/js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js'); ? (the first parameter is the name)

Comment: @danigore previously bootstrap js and css files were manually copied into their respective folders and they worked as css/bootstrap and js/bootstrap, respectively with the import command.

Comment: symfony 4? You use the encore webpack? I don't want to ask nonsense, but these work like a charm for me... so, you sure run this: `yarn encore dev`, after, when you add the new entries to webpack?

Comment: @danigore I needed to put "bootstrap": "^3.4.1", into devDependencies of package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is simple

1. Add a class to a formType field

   ```
   'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
   ```
2. Install with yarn the JQuery plugin for datepicker

   ```
   yarn add bootstrap-datepicker
   ```
3. Create a file in assets/js for datepicker configuration
    [image: Example]
4. Add in webpack encore the entry

   ```
    .addEntry('datepicker', [
       './assets/js/datepicker.js'
   ])
   ```
5. Add entry link tag in template

   ```
   {% block stylesheet %}
   {{ encore_entry_link_tags('datepicker') }}
   {% endblock %}
   ```
6. Add entry script tag in template

   ```
   {% block javascripts %}
   {{ encore_entry_script_tags('datepicker') }}
   {% endblock %}
   ```